# How to read hash table when you don't know title of column

Tags: powershell, hashtable

`$data` hash table has the following . Below output got from hash table using "$data | ConvertTo-JSON"

```
{
    "Aix_10pm":  {
                     "2022-07-23":  1.11,
                     "2022-07-24":  1.052,
                     "2022-07-27":  0.161,
                     "2022-07-31":  0.147,
                     "2022-07-26":  1.096,
                     "2022-07-21":  1.091,
                     "2022-07-30":  0.152,
                     "2022-07-25":  1.095,
                     "2022-07-29":  0.15,
                     "2022-07-22":  1.134,
                     "2022-07-19":  1.06,
                     "2022-07-28":  0.125,
                     "2022-08-01":  0.792,
                     "2022-07-20":  1.122
                 }
}
```

To output the above I wrote

```
$data.GetEnumerator()|ForEach-Object {"{0,-20} {1,10} {2,10} {3,10} {4,10} {5,10} {6,10}  {7,10} {8,10} {9,10} {10,10} {11,10} {12,10} {13,10}  {14,10}" -f $_.name,$_.value."2022-07-28",$_.value."2022-07-27",$_.value."2022-07-26",$_.value."2022-07-25",$_.value."2022-07-24",$_.value."2022-07-23",$_.value."2022-07-22",$_.value."2022-07-21",$_.value."2022-07-20",$_.value."2022-07-19",$_.value."2022-07-18",$_.value."2022-07-17",$_.value."2022-07-16",$_.value."2022-07-15"}
```

Is there better way to put output instead of manually typing dates?

If use below
[pscustomobject] $data.Aix_10pm | Format-Table
getting output which is not complete output( showing only 10 values but there are 14 Columns)
[image]

But i would like in below format where first column is job names ( Aix_10pm and many others( in my original script)) then rest are numbers by dates and also i should be able to  append in a CSV file for importing in excel.
[image]

Comment: That looks like JSON, which does not convert to a hashtable by default. Please show how you populate $data

Comment: By now you have asked 3 times a very similar question. Please be clear in what you want to see as a minimum (display???) output. Why does the [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) (that I suggested in the first place) not satisfy your wish? How strict is the required format (as the header/ruler and the alignment)? Note that `Format-Table` can be tweaked a lot with parameters and calculated properties. It might help to check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am desperately trying to explain. i am coming up different way to explain my request. I have update at top what i like to get.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Just format the expected output in the text block. Your image doesn't even make sense, the `Aix_10pm` row isn't aligned with the date columns and there are only 9 of them while there are so many dates

Comment: It only shows 10 columns because that’s what the size of the window can fit.

Comment: Hi Doug , Above is one example ( Aix_10pm) in reality there numerous like that.  I want display by row for each job ( Aix_10pm ..etc). And i would also like this output in csv so i can import in excel.

Comment: @DougMaurer, actually (and surprisingly), unless you use `Format-Table *`, the display is limited to 10 columns even if more would fit on screen.

Comment: I suppose that’s good to know. I would’ve out-gridview or export-excel long before I desired to view that many columns in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a *tabular* representation of the hashtable entries:

If you cast the (embedded) hashtable to `[pscustomobject]`, you can pipe the result to [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) for a tabular display, with each entry becoming its own column:

```bash
[pscustomobject] $data.Aix_10pm | Format-Table *
```

Based on the requirements you added later, you are probably looking for:

```bash
$data.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  $projectName = $_
  [pscustomobject] $data[$_] | 
    Select-Object @{ Name='Project'; Expression={ $projectName } }, *
} | Format-Table *
```

Note: In order to export the resulting objects to a CSV file, replace `Format-Table *` with a call to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv).

With your sample input (converted to a nested `[hashtable]`), the above outputs:

```
Project  2022-07-23 2022-07-24 2022-07-27 2022-07-31 2022-07-26 2022-07-21 2022-07-30 2022-07-25 2022-07-29 2022-07-22 2022-07-19 2022-07-28 2022-08-01 2022-07-20
-------  ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Aix_10pm       1.11      1.052      0.161      0.147      1.096      1.091      0.152      1.095       0.15      1.134       1.06      0.125      0.792      1.122
```

An additional requirement that surfaced later was to *sort* the keys (property names) of the nested hashtable:

```bash
$data.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  $projectName = $_
  $sortedSubKeys = $data[$_].Keys | Sort-Object
  [pscustomobject] $data[$_] | 
    Select-Object (, @{ Name='Project'; Expression={ $projectName } } + $sortedSubKeys)
} | Format-Table *
```

- `$data.Keys | ForEach-Object { ... }` enumerates all keys of the top-level hashtable and processes each:

  - `$projectName = $_` stores the key at hand, reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), in variable `$projectName`
  - `$sortedSubKeys = $data[$_].Keys | Sort-Object` creates a sorted array of the keys of the nested hashtable stored in the top-level entry at hand.
  - `[pscustomobject] $data[$_]` converts the nested hashtable at hand to a `[pscustomobject]`, i.e. an object with properties that can be passed to `Format-Table` and `Export-Csv`
  - The [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call transforms this object to a different `[pscustomobject]` instance:

    - `@{ Name='Project'; Expression={ $projectName } }` is a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) that creates a property named `Project` with the value of the `$projectName` variable
    - `$sortedSubKeys` selects the existing key (property) names, but in sorted order.
    - All property names / calculated properties must be passed as a *single, flat array* to `Select-Object`'s (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter, which is what `(, ... + ...)` ensures (the unary form of the [`,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) operator constructs a single-element array, and `+` then concatenates it with the elements of the array on its RHS).
- The resulting `[pscustomobject]` instances are piped to `Format-Table`; `*` as the argument to the (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter ensures that *as many columns as will fit on screen* are displayed; by default, only up to 10 are shown, even if there's room for more.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @raju; please see my update for an explanation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a hashtable the "title" would be considered a `key`. When referring to an object, which is what you would end up with by default when using `ConvertFrom-Json`, the "title" would be considered a `property`. Going with your statement that `$data` is a hashtable and wanting to read it without knowing the key(s), you can iterate the keys to determine what keys are present

```
$data.keys
```

And you can retrieve the values with those keys.

```
$keylist = $data.keys

foreach($key in $keylist) {
    $data.$key
}
```

Comment: Hi Doug , this is hash table and above ouput i showed after converting in json. I have update in my original post what i am looking for. can you help me ?